# What are the characteristics of test code as opposed to production code

Tags: language-agnostic

I would like to know what's the main difference between test and production code in terms of characteristics like why they are different.

Comment: Do you know what test code does?

Comment: I agree that your question is a bit simplistic, nonetheless asking for meaningful definitions of these terms isn't that far fetched. In case you decide to not delete your question, please dont forget about accepting an answer at some point.

Answer (score 2):

A broad question, but let's try.

*Production* code makes up your **product**. It gets build, and either goes out to your customers, or serves their requests on (your) server(s).

*Test* code is "internally", you write it to ensure your production code behaves as expected.

So the **purpose** is simply completely different. That is the **main** difference: what that code get used for.

The "rules" that apply when writing that code are mostly similar: you strive for "clean code", simple to understand, easy to change over time.

If at all, there are subtle differences, such as: in production code, you absolutely try to avoid code *duplication*. Whereas in test code, one core aspect is to **quickly** *understand* what a test is doing. A test that does its "setup" outside of the test is *harder* to understand (because you have to scroll/jump around to collect all "context). So you rather accept duplicated (setup) code here.

In other words: both kinds of code are absolutely **crucial** for your business. You write all such code with the *same* level of scrutiny. You strive to achieve the same level of quality (but you understand that certain details are in fact a bit different).

Finally: some people even claim that test code is **more** important than production code. Your production code, that just *implements* your requirements. Theoretically, you should be able to throw away one implementation and replace it with a different one.

When you have a great test base, you can actually do that: because your tests represent an *executable* specification that tells you whether your product does what you expect it to do!

Comment: I do get what's test and production code, but I mean what's is their attributes

Comment: I told you. They are basically the same, except some subtle details.

Comment: Oh you  wrote a question/answer ! Fine ! I will check it now. You were downvoted for this one too. Tiring...

Comment: I read that. I don't understand why the dv. I don't think that you need to change anything. About the answer, a single could be improved : the git-lfs version that adds the new operation or at least the version that you used that solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think a short answer would be that in test code you test the code against expected outcomes so you can check it does what it is supposed to do.

In production the same code just runs and does what it does.